# Flickr is always opened after unlocking the screen on Note 4 running Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-note-4

Recently I have updated my mobile phone to latest firmware (3G Hutchson). All went fine, but there is one annoying thing happens almost every time I'm unlocking my phone. For some reason it's trying to load some Flickr page, every time the same: http://m.flickr.com/#/photos/71393709@N06/7854822950

I'm not sure which application is causing it, but previously everything was fine and I have not installed any new app since update.

Is there a way to find out which app is causing it, as I'm not a Flickr user and not planing to download that app?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, my unlock setup was with the fingerprint reader and the lock screen had live wallpaper of the current weather. At the bottom of that is the "flickr" ad which links to the corresponding photo on Flickr. If you touch that with your finger somehow before swiping your print, it will open when you unlock your phone.

Two choices I found: Stop using the fingerprint reader or change the live wallpaper on the lock screen.